# AsyncTask oddity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm working on the live frames that I get from the android camera. I don't treat all the frames but when I do, I create a Thread so as to keep the ui thread responsive. The thing is, that within this new thread at some point I want to update a server so I start an `Asynctask`.

According to the documentation, `Asynctasks` should be started by the UI thread. So I use `runOnUiThread` to start them. In accord with the documentation, what happens is that if I change the activity or change configuration, the activity is restarted, my task dies and I never get the server's response(which is saved in a database table). I'm curious, so I tried starting the `Asynctasks` from the worker thread, and lo! I get the server response even if the activity has changed. What is interesting is that if my UI thread is number 1 and my worker thread is number 2, the server's response treatment happens on 1 and not 2. I can more or less understand this because thread 2 has finished so the asynctask probably falls back onto thread 1, but I really don't get why this thread is still running if I'm in an other activity? does anyone know what's happening?

I'm aware that even if this effect may seem very useful, it isn't a good idea to use it. But I'm just curious about why it works this way.

Comment: check this. might help http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: If a `Handler` recieves a `Message` before rotation or any other configuration change,your message will be executed before `onPause`,if it recieves the `Message` later,it runs after the new Activity is created,you just have to handle the change and attach it to the new `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan, I already know about headless `Fragments` and I don't absolutely need the connection to persist, because I do a regular check of what hasn't been sent. I just wish to understand how the server response can still be treated even though I'm in a totally different `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

When configuration change (generally speaking), **the activity is recreated**. At that moment, you have 2 instances of Activity. The old one pending collection and the new one. Say that the old one had a worker thread W. W is pending collection. However, it is very possible that it is able to continue its work before it is collected. (If you create a thread with an infinite while loop, you can notice that it will stop but eventually.)

When you start the AsyncTask from the UI thread, results will be posted to the UI Thread (delivered in onPostExecute). When the activity is pending garbage collection, the onPostExecute will not be post to the ui thread that is DONE.

However, when you started the AsyncTask from the worker thread, results will be posted as long as the calling thread (your W thread) is there. "Is there" was described in the first paragraph of the answer.